# Constructing a value through two implicit constructors?

Tags: c++, constructor, implicit

**TLDR**: I have two templatized classes `Outer` and `Inner`. `Inner<X>` can be implicitly constructed from `X`, and `Outer<Y>` can be implicitly constructed from `Y`. Should `Outer<Inner<X>> = X()` work?

**More details:**

Suppose I have the following two classes:

```
template<typename T> 
class Inner {
  public: 
    Inner(const T& value) {}
    Inner(T&& value) {}
};

template<typename T>
class Outer {
  public:
    Outer(const T& value) {}
    Outer(T&& value) {}
};
```

Consider the following function:

```
struct SomeType{};
Outer<Inner<SomeType>> DoSomethingFails() {
  SomeType value;
  return value;      
}
```

g++ complains:

```
no viable conversion from 'SomeType' to 'Outer<Inner<SomeType> >'
note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'SomeType' to 'const Inner<SomeType> &' for 1st argument
```

But if I do the following instead:

```
Outer<Inner<SomeType>> DoSomethingWorks() {
  SomeType value;
  return Inner<SomeType>(value);      
}
```

It works. Is it reasonable to expect `DoSomethingFails` to work? If not, why? And can the code be changed in a way that `DoSomethingFails` works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first example requires two user defined conversions to compile — `SomeType -> Inner -> Outer`. However, at most one user defined conversion can be applied implicitly.

Quoting N3337, *§12.3 [class.conv]*

> 1   Type conversions of class objects can be specified by constructors and by conversion functions. These conversions are called user-defined conversions and are used for implicit type conversions (Clause 4), for initialization (8.5), and for explicit type conversions (5.4, 5.2.9).
>
> 4   At most one user-defined conversion (constructor or conversion function) is implicitly applied to a single value.

---

If the goal is to avoid having to mention `Inner<SomeType>` in the return statement, you can use list initialization.

```
Outer<Inner<SomeType>> DoSomethingWorks2() {
  SomeType value;
  return {std::move(value)};
}
```